# escaping single quotes in sed

Tags: bash, sed

In a file `test.py` which reads:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import glob

for f in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    print f
```

...I'd like to programatically replace:

`glob.glob('*.txt')`

... with:

`glob.glob('*.txt')+glob.glob('*.dat')` using `sed`.

I have tried:

```
sed -i "s,glob.glob('*.txt'),glob.glob('*.txt')+glob.glob('*.dat'),g" test.py
```

...however this does not replace the string. I have a hunch that this has to do with the use of single quotes in the string to replace and/or the interpretation of the various quotation marks in the shell itself (bash). What is going wrong?

Comment: If you have more than one place where the substitution needs to be made (if not, why not just do it by hand?), you should define a wrapper function around the call to `glob` so that there *is* only one place to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape all special regex meta characters such as `.` or `*` in search pattern.

You can use double quotes in `sed` command. Also use `&` in replacement to avoid repeating matched text again.

```
sed "s/glob\.glob('\*\.txt')/&+glob.glob('*.dat')/" test.py

#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import glob

for f in glob.glob('*.txt')+glob.glob('*.dat'):
    print f
```