# sed – Escape single quotes in variable

Tags: bash, sed, terminal

I have this command:

```
salt=123
sed -i '' "s,\/\* Replace with salts \*\/,$salt,g" ./wp-config.php
```

Which works well if I run it on a file that contains the line:

```
/* Replace with salts */
```

But if I assign `salt` to the following **multiline, with single quotes**:

```
define('AUTH_KEY',         'oT0.1IG0ajXBDk.uCy?T@d?L.LgK|D3fz={VCq/IdP0fy.ZrI~WuM-9+5:-/DyPj');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  '0PO8Zgs:g(CFkwFuIKy/[2[Kb|~BO@#+[WrmHZ dE8&u{LcPA.7P$OrH:% 7Bf=G');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'xPG6BW$d~~[!lL,e<r z~nlo}(~k^b?G`0.m!54rrRggaDbk%a7c(IRzBTx&MUUy');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'J#+Rn;lgjVzjW&X^hj/wi53Y/!B_[UClk1[H:?h6Je|$?dHSb`<n-f**RtNJl;,d');
define('AUTH_SALT',        '>ho*kxR)1M4t)zni|tpDY.wn!>|Z-sVoULi(bY|0NQu/|G-2gAq=A;$3I%|`}kNb');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', '--d5e0/8%^@Yg+3r UFAB`e-hR,;iMr.X]SOn-b~nU+aH[i5_gy]%hE<8V5LqQv1');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'k;J.$+/3)k0fU]nJ7Dtbh)a!Nr[/2m<uZNO+(:AGu!(B+cVeiXM,]ePdwRn-$~O-');
define('NONCE_SALT',       ':)M$l+-U,QqCFm>8yPa5rIu9nQ<%i4?[.&PY|X&ta-MTpBp#&z+0i?|#~`%P~7,c');
```

I get the following error:

```
sed: 1: "s,\/\* Replace with sal ...": bad flag in substitute command: '''
```

Is there a way I can totally escape the contents of the `salt` variable, and just do a flat out replace?

[Others recommend using double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42948456/escaping-single-quotes-in-sed), but I think I'm already doing that?

Comment: Oh so you mean that you want these many contents to a single variable `salt` here? Then it means we need to replace a string with these multiple lines?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 yes that is exactly correct

Comment: The problem isn't single quotes, but commas in the replacement string.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't be using `sed` at all...

Comment: And `&` in the replacement string.

Comment: `following multiline` sed doesn't handle multiline replacement strings because `sed` commands are delimetered by a newline.

Comment: I'm a +1 on the "shouldn't be using `sed` at all" side of the world. See the `awk`-based `gsub_literal` function in [BashFAQ #21](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021), which is a much better fit-to-task.

Comment: Incidentally, we already have SO questions here about doing arbitrary replacements, in which `gsub_literal` is already given as an answer; see f/e https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31110862/how-to-safely-handle-n-with-sed-on-automated-scripts-where-n-can-be-in-the -- @KamilCuk, as someone who's taken a closer look at this question than I have, can you opine on whether/why this is or is not duplicative?

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy this is my first bash script so I might be trying to fit a square peg in a round hole...

Answer (score 0):

Write the replacement string into a temporary file and then use `r` sed command.

With bash command redirection this is just:

```
sed '/\/\* Replace with salts \*\/{ s/.*//; r'"<(cat <<<"$salt")"$'\n''}' ./wp-config.php
```

Remember that sed command are delimetered with a newline, you need a newline after `r` command (the `;` will not work).

The command above matches the regex `\/\* Replace with salts \*\` and if matched, substitutes current line for nothing and then appends the output of `$salt` variable to the output. Because it "appends", you will see an empty line prepended to `$salt` output.

Tested with:

```
salt=$(cat <<'EOF'                                                                                  
define('AUTH_KEY',         'oT0.1IG0ajXBDk.uCy?T@d?L.LgK|D3fz={VCq/IdP0fy.ZrI~WuM-9+5:-/DyPj');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  '0PO8Zgs:g(CFkwFuIKy/[2[Kb|~BO@#+[WrmHZ dE8&u{LcPA.7P$OrH:% 7Bf=G');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'xPG6BW$d~~[!lL,e<r z~nlo}(~k^b?G`0.m!54rrRggaDbk%a7c(IRzBTx&MUUy');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'J#+Rn;lgjVzjW&X^hj/wi53Y/!B_[UClk1[H:?h6Je|$?dHSb`<n-f**RtNJl;,d');
define('AUTH_SALT',        '>ho*kxR)1M4t)zni|tpDY.wn!>|Z-sVoULi(bY|0NQu/|G-2gAq=A;$3I%|`}kNb');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', '--d5e0/8%^@Yg+3r UFAB`e-hR,;iMr.X]SOn-b~nU+aH[i5_gy]%hE<8V5LqQv1');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'k;J.$+/3)k0fU]nJ7Dtbh)a!Nr[/2m<uZNO+(:AGu!(B+cVeiXM,]ePdwRn-$~O-');
define('NONCE_SALT',       ':)M$l+-U,QqCFm>8yPa5rIu9nQ<%i4?[.&PY|X&ta-MTpBp#&z+0i?|#~`%P~7,c');
EOF
)

cat >wp-config.php  <<'EOF'
dfasfsda
/* Replace with salts */
fdasdfsa
EOF
```

the command will output:

```
dfasfsda

define('AUTH_KEY',         'oT0.1IG0ajXBDk.uCy?T@d?L.LgK|D3fz={VCq/IdP0fy.ZrI~WuM-9+5:-/DyPj');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  '0PO8Zgs:g(CFkwFuIKy/[2[Kb|~BO@#+[WrmHZ dE8&u{LcPA.7P$OrH:% 7Bf=G');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'xPG6BW$d~~[!lL,e<r z~nlo}(~k^b?G`0.m!54rrRggaDbk%a7c(IRzBTx&MUUy');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'J#+Rn;lgjVzjW&X^hj/wi53Y/!B_[UClk1[H:?h6Je|$?dHSb`<n-f**RtNJl;,d');
define('AUTH_SALT',        '>ho*kxR)1M4t)zni|tpDY.wn!>|Z-sVoULi(bY|0NQu/|G-2gAq=A;$3I%|`}kNb');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', '--d5e0/8%^@Yg+3r UFAB`e-hR,;iMr.X]SOn-b~nU+aH[i5_gy]%hE<8V5LqQv1');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'k;J.$+/3)k0fU]nJ7Dtbh)a!Nr[/2m<uZNO+(:AGu!(B+cVeiXM,]ePdwRn-$~O-');
define('NONCE_SALT',       ':)M$l+-U,QqCFm>8yPa5rIu9nQ<%i4?[.&PY|X&ta-MTpBp#&z+0i?|#~`%P~7,c');
fdasdfsa
```

Comment: If you don't want the empy line, you can do `r` first, then `d`, something like `sed -e '\#pattern#{r salts' -e 'd}'` (where `salts` is just a file containing the replacement strings).